# Emulator to Physical

Tags: android, android-emulator

**Emulator --- Device**

Hey people. I'm not very experienced in Android development, so I would like to know what I have to expect.

I wrote an app of about 1000 lines of code, which is running perfectly fine in the emulator. So what will it be like when I install it on a physical device? Ain't got one here at the moment, but I will get my hands on one on the next days. Will there be a bunch of nasty errors? Just some design stuff? Errors, that cant be reproduced in the emulator?

Thanks in advance

EnflamedSoul

Comment: My experience:Physical device is much faster!!! There should be no other/different errors on a physical device. But maybe you have to fix the layout a little bit. The graphics can be displayed in another quality and so on.

Comment: Depends on many things - if you built it against, say Android 2.2 but your real device is using an older release, you might be using features older versions don't have. The speed will probably be much better, the emulator is pretty slow.

Comment: Does your app do anything that is device specific? does it use location services? or try to access hardware dependent Apis? Does it do anything that is affected by timing? Does it do audio capture?

Comment: No. My app is a newsreader, fetching json data from a server and displaying it in Standardviews. I already tested several different screen resolutions in the emu and landscape etc. No problem at all. Minimum API level for this app is 4, so built for 1.6+.

Comment: Probably will be fine, but you will see when you get your device.

Comment: Make sure you check out screen orientation changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: emulator runs the real Android code. It emulates ARM device and runs the whole stack on top: linux kernel, libs, android code. It is the same as device sans some hardware (camera, mobile network stuff, gps) and much slower.

```
So what will it be like when I install it on a physical device? 
Will there be a bunch of nasty errors?
```

No problems really. It should work ok.

```
Just some design stuff?
```

If you set your emulator to the same resolution and pixel density of your device, then it should look identical.

```
Errors, that cant be reproduced in the emulator?
```

There ares some thing that you can not do in emulator: primarily make calls and use camera. Otherwise emulator behaves like a plain phone.

Comment: You can emulate the camera and phone calls in the emulator though

Comment: I know that calls can be simulated and also the Camera button click can be emulated. But you can not record a video or snap a photo (pr simulate that). http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#limitations

Answer (score 1):

My Android apps have all been very simple, but I have really only had to make small changes to their layouts when I tried them on my phone. Over-all, the process of moving to the phone was a rather painless one.

Answer (score 1):

I had a code that took 4 minutes on the emulator to complete, and on the real device it is just 10 seconds.